# Find Value from NodeJs Model using Or and Not Null operators

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, sequelize.js

I'm attempting to look in a database (Postgres) and grab a user based on email or a special sso_id (unique to the IDP). I'm using Node and Node models. The situation is i'll receive an email, or this sso id, I want to get the email, or the sso id (and make sure the sso id is not null)

here's my code that doesn't work

```
return User.findOne({
    where: {
      $or: [
        {email: userId},
        {
          sso_id: userId,
          $ne: {
            sso_id: null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  })
```

**Solution:** with some help from [rakesh-rocking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6613422/rakesh-rocking)

```
return User.findOne({
    where: {
      $or: [
        {email: userId},
        {
          $and: [
            {sso_id: userId},
            {
              sso_id: {$ne: null}
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this,

```
  return User.findOne({
    where: {
      $or: [
        {email: userId},
        {
          $and:[
         {sso_id: userId},{

            sso_id: {$ne:null}

         }
         ]
        }
      ]
    }
  })
```

Comment: did not work, but I'm going to play with this a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
return User.findOne({
    where: {
      $or: [
        {email: userId},
        {
          $and: [
            {sso_id: userId},
            {
              sso_id: {$ne: null}
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  })
```